# Occlusion Trasparency with Masks (Lineart modifier)

Tags: lineart

[Occlusion Masks](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/line_art.html) can be used to set variable Transparency/Color  on lines generated with Lineart Modifier.

However ,***the workflow to create these masks and set bit transparency on them is not provided.***

How to set variable Transparency  on lines generated with Lineart Modifier with Occlusion Masks?

[image]

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile expanding the question a bit, to include more detail on how to setup the scene for the line art and occlusion masks since it's not a familiar feature to some users. For example, creating a Grease Pencil  objects, setting it up for line art, anything else that is required to set up an example like in your image.